# How to send data to Databse in CMS Made Simple

Tags: cmsmadesimple

I am quite new to CMS MAde Simple. I am not able to understand how the
data can be saved to database. I think its in smarty framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing form data in your database is actually a built-in feature of the FormBuilder module.
To do this add a new field to your form, and choose "*Store Results In Database" as the type of field. Data will be stored in an XML format in the [PREFIX]_module_fb_formbrowser database table.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion......Can u plz tell me how can i get resolved the formbrowser component's database disposition error. where it can be fixed....Please help me. Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It uses ADOdb as an "interface" to the database. Basically developers of CMSMS already wrote `SQL statements` for update and delete content. I am really sorry but this is a very wide topic. The actual purpose of a CMS is to remove the burden from the user to actually know these kinds of stuff. I suggest you first do some reading on PHP, SQL and then come back with a more specific question.

[SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)

[PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/)

[CMS Made Simple Documentation](http://www.cmsmadesimple.org/apidoc/)

Comment: thnx, is there any built in module where i can create a form and submit data (request for quote) and store it

Comment: Ah. I see why are you asking for a database interface. Have you tried their [Formbuilder](http://wiki.cmsmadesimple.org/index.php/User_Handbook/Admin_Panel/Extensions/Form_Builder#Formbuilder)?

Comment: yes i have created 9-10 different fields and wants to store field data to database...How can i achieve this...Please help me out.Thank you...!!!